# z.Hd. (unbekanntes Ge­schlecht) Mustermann

Tags: word-usage, salutation

Ich habe einen Brief vom Finanzamt bekommen, der ist von einem Beamten (einer Beamtin) unterschrieben. Wie es sehr oft passiert, ist der Nachname in Klammern geschrieben.

> Mit freundlichem Gruß
> (Mustermann)

Das Geschlecht des Absenders ist mir nicht bekannt. Ich möchte aber die Antwort direkt an den Absender senden. Dafür möchte ich die Form "z.Hd. ..." nutzen, z.B.:

> Finanzamt Hannover-Land I
>   **z.Hd....**
>   Postfach 91 03 20
>   30423 Hannover

Wie soll ich die Form richtig verwenden?
Soweit habe ich nur zwei Varianten:

- z.Hd. (Mustermann)
- z.Hd. Herrn/Frau Mustermann

Comment: Gibt es im Briefkopf bzw. oben rechts noch "unser Zeichen" und "Ihr Zeichen"? Dann wäre mein Ansatz: `z. Hd. Mustermann (Zeichen xxx)`. Also das "(Zeichen xxx)" im eigenen Briefkopf verwenden und falls Briefumschlag mit Klarsichtfolie für den Adressbereich, dann auch. Nur falls der Umschlag manuell beschrieben wird, würde ich das "(Zeichen xxx)" weglassen.

Comment: Oh Mann (facepalm), einfach weglassen diese Zeile mit "z.Hd." und fertig.

Answer (score 2):

Deine schon genannte Idee kann bei Bedarf so umgesetzt werden:

```
Finanzamt Hannover-Land I
z.Hd. Herrn/Frau XYZ
Postfach 91 03 20
30423 Hannover
```

Ein eventuell vorhandenes Aktenzeichen mit Namenskürzel gehört mit dem Hinweis "Ihr Zeichen:" unter das Adressfeld und vor den Betreff des Antwortschreibens.

Allerdings sichert die oben gezeigte Adresse keine ungeöffnet persönliche Zustellung innerhalb der Behörde, zumal der Vorname fehlt. Es kann helfen, den Namen des Mitarbeitenden in die erste Zeile vor die Bezeichnung des z. B. Finanzamtes zu setzen.

Aber VORSICHT - insbesondere bei Terminen z. B. wegen Fälligkeit von Steuern ist genau dies bei Schreiben an Behörden nicht zu empfehlen. Die Behörde muss bei entsprechenden Terminen innerhalb der Behörde auch bei Urlaub von Mitarbeitenden eine fristgerechte Bearbeitung sicherstellen.

Ein persönlich adressierter Brief bleibt bei Urlaub vielleicht ungeöffnet mehrere Wochen liegen. Daher sollte diese Art der Adressierung nur genutzt werden, wenn der vollständige Name bekannt ist und ein wiederholter Kontakt bereits bestanden hat.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn in der Anschrift eine Person genannt wird, verwenden wir aus Höflichkeit die entsprechende Anrede. Über einen Vornamen würden wir das Geschlecht der Person "erraten" und darüber die passende Anrede wählen. Genau diese Information fehlt uns hier. 
In der deutschen Sprache haben wir leider noch keine geschlechtsneutrale Anrede, daher bleibt nur, die Variante Herrn/Frau zu wählen, wohl wissend, dass es inzwischen andere geschlechtliche Identitäten gibt, für die beides eigentlich nicht die passende Anrede ist.
Die Anrede aus dem Mangel an Informationen einfach wegzulassen, kann als grob unhöflich empfunden werden.

Answer (score 0):

Ich unterscheide zwischen einem undurchsichtigen Umschlag und einem mit Fenster:

Für den undurchsichtigen Umschlag:

> Finanzamt Hannover-Land I
>   z.Hd. Mustername 
>   Postfach 91 03 20
>   30423 Hannover

Im Briefkopf, egal ob Umschlag mit oder ohne Fenster:

> Finanzamt Hannover-Land I
>   z.Hd. Mustername (Zeichen xxx) 
>   Postfach 91 03 20
>   30423 Hannover

Warum die Unterscheidung? Persönliche Meinung.

D.h., ich kenne Behörden-/ Finanzamtabläufe zu wenig, um zu wissen, ob die zentrale Poststelle sowieso alles öffnet oder nach Möglichkeit eine "z. Hd."-Addressierung auch verschlossen zugestellt wird.

Aufgrund der Möglichkeit, dass ein Name häufiger vorkommt, würde ich das Zeichen des Absenders (im empfangenen Brief meist rechts oben) entsprechend mit angeben.

Im Brief selbst erfolgt nochmal die Referenzierung auf den empfangenen Betreff, spätestens da kann eine zentrale Brieföffnungsstelle den/ die zuständigen Bearbeiter/-in ermitteln.

Comment: Diese Antwort scheint an der Frage, wie ein Empfänger unbekannten Geschlechts per z.Hd. genannt wird, vorbeizugehen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: abgesehen von der Ungenauigkeit, die ... nicht als *Mustername* zu schreiben (war in der Frage auch als ...), wüsste ich nicht warum. Daher: inwiefern geht es an der Frage vorbei, wenn es um das Adressfeld geht? Wo habe ich überlesen, dass es um die Anrede im Brief geht? Um die Anrede am Telefon?

Comment: Ich lese die Frage so, dass ganz konkret gefragt wird, wie die "z.Hd."-Zeile in der Empfängeranschrift einer Postsendung zu schreiben ist, wenn nur der Nachname des Empfängers bekannt ist - es geht also um die Formulierung bzw. Konvention, welche Anrede etc. verwendet werden sollte. In deiner Antwort wird einfach ohne Kommentar oder Begründung nur der Nachname verwendet; statt dessen folgen Spekulationen über die amtsinterne Zuordnung des Antwortschreibens.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Falls nur der Nachname bekannt ist, kann ich nur den Nachnamen angeben. Daher habe ich m.E. die Formulierung in der "z.Hd."-Zeile in der Empfängeranschrift für eine Postsendung angegeben. Editiert um Mustername. Scheint dem zu entsprechen, was Du in der Frage als "gesucht" gelesen hast. Dazu die Spekulation, wie hilfreich die Angabe von "Ihr Zeichen" ist. Da das Geschlecht unbekannt ist, sehe ich keinen Gewinn darin, "Herr/ Frau" zu schreiben. (zumal mich das Geschlecht meines Gegenübers in Amtsgeschäften 0 interessiert)

Comment: "Falls nur der Nachname bekannt ist, kann ich nur den Nachnamen angeben." - oder "Herr/Frau" davorsetzen, oder "Herr oder Frau", oder "n.a.", oder den Nachnamen in Anführungszeichen setzen ... genau das ist mE die Frage, was an der Stelle üblich ist. "Da das Geschlecht unbekannt ist, sehe ich keinen Gewinn darin, 'Herr/ Frau' zu schreiben." - inhaltlich stimme ich dir ja zu, formulierungstechnisch klingt *nur* der Nachname vielleicht schon etwas merkwürdig. Letztendlich spielt es aber gar keine Rolle, was du oder ich sinnvoll finden, wenn nach der gängigen Konvention gefragt ist.

Comment: *Falls* die Unterschrift/der Absender ein Initial beinhaltet (M. Mustermann), empfiehlt es sich, dieses auf jeden Fall mit anzugeben - auf Herrn/Frau würde ich dann verzichten.